# Comparing text values to target text row

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make my Google Sheets (that is populated with textual responses from Google Forms) to color the background of the "wrong" cells red. I have the correct answer for each column at the very top in row 1. These are all alphabetical text, not numerical answers.

How would I go about in having it compare the values of each column to the top row?

IF the value is NOT EQUAL to the top of the column, that cell is colored.
so the "*wrong*" responses in the below example will be colored, as it isn't the same text as the top row.

____A___B___C___D__

1 **ans1 ans2 ans3 ans4**

2 *wrong* ans2 ans3 *wrong*

3 ans1 ans2 *wrong* ans4


 [LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GNHfK-q_mjxH4FBHGhtRG26RB-x3UpUqGv00acpvgsI/edit?usp=sharing) to the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format, conditional formatting, custom formula is:

`=AND(LEN(A2),A2<>A$1)`

and apply that to range A2:x, where x is the lowest and right-most cell of the range you want to apply this to.

Comment: I've come across a problem.
I used **=AND(LEN(F5),F5<>F$1)** on the range **F5:CM**, which did the job for three of my spreadsheets...but two of the spreadsheets are working up.

1) The cells with the value TRUE is being universally colored.
2) Column L colors cells with the correct target answer (from L1) of FALSE.
3) The rest of the cells show no coloring response to the "wrong" values (values that don't match the top), only coloring the cell if has the text, "TRUE". Any ideas why this might be happening?

**I made an edit to the parent question for ease of reading.**

Comment: Can you post a link to a spreadsheet, that anyone can edit (remove sensitive data first), that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GNHfK-q_mjxH4FBHGhtRG26RB-x3UpUqGv00acpvgsI/edit?usp=sharing